# create nonlinear spaced vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a vector with a variable step. Indeed, I would like that my step forward is increasing between each two elements. Also, my vector must start with an initial value and a final value (defined by myself).

I tried with the `logspace` function in MATLAB but it is not the best solution for me.

[image: illustration]

Comment: What should the spacing then be, if not logarithmic? You will have to be more specific about what you want, and about why `logspace` isn’t suitable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

```
vec = x0+(x1-x0)*linspace(0,1,N).^alpha;
```

where x0 is the starting point, x1 is the end point, the vector length is N, and alpha is some nonlinear spacing ...

example:

```
vec = 2+1*linspace(0,1,10).^4

2.0000    2.0002    2.0024    2.0123    2.0390    2.0953    2.1975    2.3660    2.6243    3.0000
```